# Use Database Information From External PHP file

Tags: php

I have my database information file called main-custom.php file which have information in array like this

```
<?php defined('MW_PATH') || exit('No direct script access allowed');

return array(

    // application components
    'components' => array(
        'db' => array(
            'connectionString'  => 'mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=databasebane',
            'username'          => 'username',
            'password'          => 'password',
            'tablePrefix'       => 'mw_',
        ),
    ),
    // params
    'params' => array(
        'email.custom.header.prefix' => 'X-Ltxf-'
    ),
);
```

Its in Mailwizz.I am looking for get and use this database information in my another file so I have included it in my index.php file like below

```
<?php
define("MW_PATH","OK");
require_once("../apps/common/config/main-custom.php");
```

Now I am not getting idea how I can use this database information for create variable like

```
$connectionString =?
$username =?
.....
```

Since main-custom.php file returning array, its making me confused and not able to get information from it to my index.php file.

since **mailwizz** is using main-custom.php as it so I can not modify it. **Is there any way to extract required information from it to index.php file without modify it?**

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try `$x = require '../apps/common/config/main-custom.php';` and `print_f(x)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two considerations here.

Firstly, the constant `MW_PATH` acts to prevent you from executing the rest of the content, so we need to define that.

Secondly, the actual code is just a `return` statement. That only makes sense inside a function or class method, so we need to mock up that environment.

This gives us:

```
// define the constant if its not already defined.
if (!defined('MW_PATH')) define('MW_PATH', 'OK');

// create the function and include the file in it.
function getDBdata() {
require("main-custom.php");
}

// call the function to get the data
$dbData = getDBdata();

$connectionString = $dbData['components']['db']['connectionString']  // mysql:host=localhost...

Note that defining MW_PATH to an arbitrary value may cause problems later in the code if it is redefined, or has an incorrect value.
```

Comment: When I implement code like you have told, its not giving me anything.

Comment: print_r($dbData);die(); giving me empty result. Thanks!

Comment: aah, Its working fine, You just missed return statement in function called getDBdata, thats why it was not working.

Comment: Well, that's weird because the code you posted in your question includes a `return`

Comment: Yes, I understand but as soon as I have added return statement in your function, its started giving me expected result. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Manisha which means that whole function business (as well as entire answer) is essentially **useless** (not to mention it's incorrect)

Answer (score -1):

I have achieved it using **file_get_contents** like below

```
$content = str_replace(' ', '', file_get_contents("../apps/common/config/main-custom.php"));

$db_host ="localhost";
$db_port ="3306";
$db_name = get_string_between($content, 'dbname=', "',");
$username = get_string_between($content, "'username'=>'", "',");
$password = get_string_between($content, "'password'=>'", "',");
$tablePrefix = get_string_between($content, "'tablePrefix'=>'", "',");

function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}
```

Its working fine as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

assign $app = require_once("../apps/common/config/main-custom.php")

Comment: as I have told in question, since main_custom.php is used in other system, I can not modify it.

Comment: then, use the second option, where you assign in index.php $app = require_once("../apps/common/config/main-custom.php")

Comment: that was already proposed